# C# insert combo box item index in small int column

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I want to insert the selected item index from a combobox into a `tinyint` column (`FoodType`) in SQL Server. I wrote the code below, but I get an exception:

> Must declare the scalar variable @fType

What must I do?

```
string query = "INSERT INTO MenuTbl (FoodName,FoodType,FoodUnit, SalePrice)" +
               "VALUES (@fName, @fType, @fUnit, @fPrice)";

connection = new SqlConnection(conectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", FNameTextBox.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fTyp", TypeComboBox.SelectedIndex + 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@funit", UnitComboBox.SelectedIndex +1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fprice", int.Parse(PriceEdit.Text));

connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: you have a typo change `@fTyp` to `@fType` to match with the parameter passed to `VALUES`

Comment: The error message seems _very_ clear, if you looks at your variables you should be able to spot one letter missing in a five-letter variable name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing an "e" on the parameter?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fTyp", TypeComboBox.SelectedIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a typo with this line of code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fTyp", TypeComboBox.SelectedIndex + 1);
```

It should be @fType atleast according to your select query

```
 string query = "Insert into MenuTbl (FoodName,FoodType,FoodUnit, SalePrice)" +
         "VALUES (@fName,@fType,@fUnit, @fPrice)";
```

And I also think that `TypeComboBox.SelectedIndex + 1` will only give you the index+1 numerical value rather than the selected text contents. Is that what you want?